# CRUD operation working at sub-collection but not in parent-Collection (Firestore : PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions Code: 7)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Why I am able to do CRUD operations at subCollections but not at parentCollection?
Idealy if I am able to read and write at nested sub-collection why not the same at parent collection?

[Sharing images of my Firebase Firestore Database]

Architecture :
[Parent Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujBMF.png)
[Sub Collection (nested collection)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27OiG.png)

Current **Firebase Rules**:
[Firebase Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHo0F.png)

Current **Firebase Indexes**:
[Firebase indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LdiI.png)

Code (Which was working earlier) ❌

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("participants")
            .document("123456789")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapShot ->
                // Actual code removed for readibility
                Log.d("Screen B", "${documentSnapShot.data}")
            }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->  
                exception.printStackTrace()
            }
```

`

**Issue I am facing**

The above code is throwing exception :
`PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Whenever I am trying to access the parent Collection documents using the above code,
firebase is throwing this exception.
Earlier the code was working, until I did some changes at the **Firebase Rules**.

But weirdly, if I try to access the sub-collection like `user-data` collection, I am able to fetch data perfectly.

Code for fetching sub-collection ✅

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collectionGroup("user_data")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
              // removed actual code for readability 
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.e("AllParticipantScreen", "Exception : Caught ${it.message}")
            }
```

The Changes at the Firebase rules, before things started to breaking :

- Added rules for collection groups using recurssive wildcards -> document=**
- Made some changes in the `Firebase Indexes` page (img added above) [to implement search functionailty]

Things I tried so far :

- Download and replaced old google-services.json with new one
- Tried and made changes in the Firebase Rules

Images for Firebase Rules I tried before which are not working :

[Firebase rule set one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsZE1.png)
[Firebase rule set two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz58S.png)

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will also help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set read and write permission to each document that exists under the `participants` collection until a specific date, then you should consider using the following rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /participants/{participantId} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2024, 4, 12);
    }
    match /participants/{participantId}/user_data/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2024, 4, 12);
    }
  }
}
```

The above rules will allow the read and write operation until 2024-04-12.

Comment: Hey nikeight. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for responding to my question, 
Those rules are working fine if I only wanted to read and write to participants' collection documents only. 
But now the other request for the sub-collection `user_data` has stopped working.

More Context : 
I have also implemented a search operation in my Android app, which fetches all the data from the `user_data` sub-collection. 

(Which stopped working if I use the above rules you suggested ) 

I am updating my answer, which I did to make everything work in my application for now. 
Please let me know if it has any disadvantages or not.

Comment: To make the `user_data` work, please see my updated answer. Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

This is the firebase rule, I updated it in order to make things work,
Please mark/comment, if I am doing anything wrong or can have some issues later.

[Sharing image of my current Firebase rule.]

[image: Firebase rules updated to make thing work]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)